# How can I get the ItemID from any Amazon product url

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to get the

> ItemID

```
From any product url on Amazon for ex. :

http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0140RDK8W/ref=s9_simh_gw_g107_i2_r?ie=UTF8&fpl=fresh&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=desktop-1&pf_rd_r=0539QT0WGAX6VJZ73PV9&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=2437869742&pf_rd_i=desktop
```

How can I get the product URL from this url ?

Answer (score 2):

`B0140RDK8W` is what you want actually.
It's called "ASIN" (Amazon Standard Identifier Number), in the API call, you can specified the it like this `IdType=ASIN&ItemId=B0140RDK8W`

also you can try it easily through the tool [Product Advertising API Scratchpad](http://webservices.amazon.com/scratchpad/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

// PHP

> $query = parse_url($url);
>
> $params = explode('/', $query['path']);
>
> $itemID = $params[3];

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Javascript version I just created:

```
var sliceItAgain = mUrl.slice(0, mUrl.indexOf("?"));
var sliceItAgain2 = sliceItAgain.slice(sliceItAgain.indexOf("B0"), sliceItAgain.length);
    var ASIN;

    if(sliceItAgain2.includes("/"))
    {
        var thirdSlice = sliceItAgain2.slice(0, sliceItAgain2.indexOf("/"));
        ASIN = thirdSlice;
    }
    else
    {
        ASIN = sliceItAgain2;
    }
```